RabbitMQ Utilizing multiple consumer thread from consumer application
how can I Utilize multiple consumer thread from one consumer application,
this is my code
this is my main function i just call 3 threads and give the the function ConsumeMessages
but it end up using just one thread
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
Order is Being Processed, Thread Id: 5
<pre>
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Starting");


      // Define the number of consumers (threads) you want
      int numberOfConsumers = 3;

      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfConsumers; i++)
      {
          // Start a new thread for each consumer
         var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConsumeMessages));
          thread.Start();
      }

   var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
   waitHandle.WaitOne();
  }
</pre>

This is my function, ConsumeMessages. I literally do everything in it. I create a new connection and channel for each thread. Initially, I wanted to have the same connection but have a channel for each thread, but this also doesn't work, as the work is done by just one thread. I also set the prefetch to 1 so that each thread would consume one message at a time
<pre>
private static void ConsumeMessages()
{
          var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };

using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = connection.CreateModel();
channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false); // Set the prefetch count to 1 for each consumer

Console.WriteLine($"Create channel, Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "MS",
        durable: false,
        exclusive: false,
        autoDelete: false,
        arguments: null);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

Console.WriteLine($"Create consumer, Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
{
var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
var orderInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OrderDto>(message);
Console.WriteLine($"Order is Being Processed, Thread Id:    {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
await OrderCheckOut(orderInfo!);
Console.WriteLine($"Order Processed");
};

channel.BasicConsume(queue: "MS", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
}
</pre>

The above function simply calls another function to update something

I assume you are trying to achieve better throughput by creating 3 consuming threads, but you should almost never resort to manually managing threads. You are mutch better off using the async api.
The rabbitmq library has builting support for asynchronous messaging https://www.rabbitmq.com/client-libraries/dotnet-api-guide#consuming-async
You can then configure the message consumption concurrency to your needs by configuring the ConsumerDispatchConcurrency https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/api/RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.html#RabbitMQ_Client_ConnectionFactory_ConsumerDispatchConcurrency
